# closure of. a point

Tags: general-topology

I have this topology  on $\mathbb{R}^2$

$\tau=\{\emptyset\}\cup \{\Omega_r, r\geq0\}$ where $\Omega_r=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, (x-2)^2+(y+2)^2\geq r^2\}$

How to find the closure of the center $cl(\{(2,-2)\})$?

The only open which intersect the center is $\Omega_0=\mathbb{R}^2$

how to continue ?

Comment: What do you mean by *center*?

Comment: $Omega_r$ is the complement of the disc of center (2,-2) and reduce r

Answer (score 3):

The set $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(2,-2)\}=\bigcup_{r\gt0}\Omega_r$ is open.  Thus $\{(2,-2)\}$ is closed, and is its own closure.

Comment: but is $\cup_{r>0}\Omega_r$ open in this topology ?

Comment: Arbitrary unions of open sets are open.

Comment: Technically you need to consider the topology _generated_ by the open sets you gave.

Comment: Your comment is a good point: $\tau$ is a base for a topology, but $\tau$ is not a topology because $\cup_{r>0}\Omega_r \not \in \tau$.